# Error : "android.databinding.tool.processing.ScopedException: [databinding] {"msg":"Only one layout element with 1 view child is allowed."

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, android-databinding

Tried alot of stuffs any of them are not working please see through it! 
Tried- adding data, adding LinearLayout to all and a few more..

```xml
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/myNavHostFragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />

</layout>
```

Comment: First, if you are going to use data binding, and you are going to have a layout with a `<layout>` root element, you *must* have exactly two children of that `<layout>` root element. The first is a `<data>` element describing the data binding, and the second is the root `View` or `ViewGroup` representing your view hierarchy. You have three children, not two, and none of them is a `<data>` element.

Answer (score 1):

Only one  element with 1 view child is allowed.

you have three DrawerLayout, LinearLayout and NavigationView

Try to wrap all inside the drawerLayout tag

**Example**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                android:id="@+id/myNavHostFragment"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:menu="@menu/navdrawer_menu"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"/>

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</layout>
```